# jquery mobile - forcing panel open on wider screens

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've been trying to test my jquery mobile app on multiple devices.  I currently have a panel that is opened via swipe or clicking on a 'menu' button.

However, on wide screens, the app just looks funky.  WAY too wide.  I understand this is meant for mobile, but, why not format it for ipads/surface/androids as well?

To do this, I'd like to shorten the width by requiring the panel to be open at all times when the width exceeds a specific value.

I've dug through the documentation, and the closest thing I found was:

`class="ui-responsive-panel"` from the following link: http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/docs/widgets/panels/panel-fixed.php

After adding it to my page header, I noticed that I can't 'swipe' the menu away when the window is wide.  When I shrink the window (either on a pc browser, or by rotating the device), it can be swiped.

Is anyone familiar with this, and willing to shed some light?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for this as well. Let me know if you get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm facing the same problem. I want the panel to stay open when the user turns the device in landscape mode (tablets) or if the window is wider than a specific width at the very beginning.

Unfortunately I did not find any solutions and the jQuery Mobilele example for responsive panels in this case.

So I found a way by using some javascript but I'm not happy with this solutions since a pure CSS solution with media queries would be nicer.

However, here is my "workaround" solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onresize = function (event) {
        if (window.innerWidth > 800) {
            window.setTimeout(openPanel, 1);
        }
        if (window.innerWidth < 800) {
            window.setTimeout(closePanel, 1);
        }
    };

    function closePanel() {
        $("#mypanel").panel("close");
    }
    function openPanel() {
        $("#mypanel").panel("open");
    }

    $( "#mypanel" ).on( "panelcreate", function( event, ui ) {
        if (window.innerWidth > 800) {
            openPanel();
        }
        if (window.innerWidth < 800) {
            closePanel();
        }

    });
</script>
```

So if the window inner width is higher than 800, the panel opens; if it is lower than 800 it closes. Furthermore the `window.onresize` function is required to provide the same functionality in case the user turns the device from portrait mode to landscape mode.

Hope it helped. But I'm still looking for a better solution ;)

Comment: ah. nice.  certainly gets the job done and is a nice start.  I haven't implemented this yet, but does it close when you tap the content area like it would in its normal use?

Comment: You can just add the class "ui-responsive-panel" to your page wrapper (data-role=page element). http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/panels/  

then you should edit your media query in the jqm css (@media (min-width:35em) to the same width you chose in the js i posted above.

Answer (score 2):

I found a css-only solution for that issue that is much simpler.
In the media query for your responsive panel `@media (min-width:55em){...}` add/overwrite the following css classes:

```
.ui-panel-closed {  width: 17em; }

.ui-panel-content-wrap.ui-body-c.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-wrap-closed{     margin-left:17em; }
```

The second class might be different to yours depending on the swatch you are using; in this case it is "C". However, just take the content wrap class that wraps all your header,content, footer area.

In my example I used a panel with `data-display="reveal" data-position="left"` If you want it appearing on the right hand side just change `margin-left:17em` to `margin-right:17em`

If you want the panel to behave like "overlay", just forget about the second class i posted...
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the problem right now and I found the solution of mJay really useful. However it would be great to use media queries instead, something like this perhaps:

```
 @media (min-width:35em){
    .ui-panel{
        width:30em;
    }
    .ui-panel-close { width:30em; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is my "CSS" solution.  What you need to know: `mnuMenu` is the id of the panel that I want to always have visible on the left side of the screen and `lnkMenu` is the id of the a tag for the button which normally shows the panel on smaller screen widths.

```
    @media all and (min-width: 900px)
    {
        #mnuMenu
        {
            visibility: visible;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            float: left;
            width: 300px;
            height: 100vh;
            background: none;
            -webkit-transition: none !important;
            -moz-transition: none !important;
            transition: none !important;
            -webkit-transform: none !important;
            -moz-transform: none !important;
            transform: none !important;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            -moz-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;           
        }

        #lnkMenu
        {
            display: none;
        }

        .ui-content
        {
            margin-left: 325px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This isn't working as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.5. And I don't think it would ever work for any version, if your app uses headers or footers, as their left margin isn't adjusted properly.