# Responsive jquery panel to stay open and hide menu on wide screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

The jquery demo page automatically open the side panel on wide screens and shows a logo image instead of the 'open panel' icon. It stays open and does not really act like a panel until the screen gets smaller. See the page here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/

I have tried to recreate this in CSS by  following the instructions here: [jquery mobile - forcing panel open on wider screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960044/jquery-mobile-forcing-panel-open-on-wider-screens/15384263#15384263)

but it doesn't work. I have gone through the js and css files of the JQM demo site, but I do not see how this achieved (or what to look for). I have ui-responsive-panel on my page element too, but no go. How does one achieve this responsive effect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery mobile - forcing panel open on wider screens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960044/jquery-mobile-forcing-panel-open-on-wider-screens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery demo page achieves that effect via [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

They work by including something like this in your CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .class1 {
    display: none;
  }
  .class2 {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

Any styles inside `@media (max-width: 600px)` will only be applied if the browser window is below 600px (as implied by `max-width: 600px`).

Using media queries, you can simply style your side panel differently when the browser window is below (or above) a certain size.

**Edit**: You can search the [jQuery demo page's CSS](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/_assets/css/jqm-demos.css) for `@media` for a closer look at their implementation.

Comment: Hi, that was my initial approach. I tried using their whole @media sections, but the panel remained closed.

Comment: I select yours as the answer because I went back to the @media section for a triple look (turns out I had a class named incorrectly).