# Force panel to stay open on wider screens in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, navigation, panel

I want to create a mobile page for mobiles and tablets. When the user uses a tablet (larger screen), the left panel-navigation should stay open all time. When the user uses a mobile phone (smaller screen) there should be only a button top-left to open the panel.

Jquery has a demo, but obviously it is not working:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-responsive/

I tried the demo on JSfiddle but it also did not work:

```
    <div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos ui-responsive-panel" id="panel-responsive-page1" data-title="Panel responsive page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Panel responsive</h1>
        <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
        <a href="#add-form" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth">

        <h1>Panel responsive</h1>

        <p>This is a typical page that has two buttons in the header bar that open panels. The left panel has the push display mode, the right panel reveal. To make this responsive, you can make the page re-flow at wider widths. This allows both the panel menu and page to be used together when more space is available. This behavior is controlled by CSS media queries. You can create a custom one for a specific breakpoint or use the breakpoint preset by adding the <code>class="ui-responsive-panel"</code> to the page container. We have added this class on this demo page. Note that when using the preset class, we also hide the dismiss layer on wider screens if the panel has the push display mode.</p>

        <div data-demo-html="#panel-responsive-page1"></div><!--/demo-html -->

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <a href="../" data-rel="back" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-mini ui-btn-inline ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-icon-left ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon">Back</a>

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="panel" data-display="push" data-theme="b" id="nav-panel">

        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Accordion</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Ajax Navigation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Autocomplete</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Buttons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Checkboxes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Collapsibles</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Controlgroup</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Dialogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Fixed toolbars</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Flip switch toggle</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Footer toolbar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Form elements</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Grids</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Header toolbar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Icons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Links</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Listviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Loader overlay</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Navbar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Navbar, persistent</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Pages</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">New</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Popup</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Radio buttons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Select</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Slider, single</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">New</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">New</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">New</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Text inputs & textarea</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Transitions</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- /panel -->

    <div data-role="panel" data-position="right" data-display="reveal" data-theme="a" id="add-form">

        <form class="userform">

            <h2>Login</h2>

            <label for="name">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true">

            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off" data-mini="true">

            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-b ui-mini">Cancel</a></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-mini">Save</a></div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div><!-- /panel -->

</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="panel-responsive-page2">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Landing page</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content">

        <p>This is just a landing page.</p>

        <a href="#panel-responsive-page1" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left">Back</a>

    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/84m0b2au/

I searched a long time, found a half-working JS solution, but the panel does not stay open when i change the pages, only when i reload the page. I found some similar questions, obviousl it is an issue, but nowhere is a (for me) working solution.

So my question is, how can i solve the problem. The best way is to find a CSS-only solution.

Thank you very much for your tips.

Comment: I think that demo is for the Page content to be responsive when you open the panel not the other way round. You can try my Jquery method and put the width at first load in a cookie or variable  and run the open panel function at pageshow. It may work. --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924426/jquery-mobile-responsive-panels/26931622#26931622  -- or view the page source here to see how JQM site added a menu on the side and hide the open panel button on wider screens ---- http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works on one page, but when i link the page to a duplicated one, the panel will not be shown any more on the second page.

Comment: If i get a chance ill do a Demo to see if i can resolve the issue with the Panel not staying Open when you navigate.

Comment: This would be great, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery mobile - forcing panel open on wider screens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960044/jquery-mobile-forcing-panel-open-on-wider-screens)