# JQuery Mobile - Responsive Panel - force panel to stay open on wider screens - pure CSS solution

Tags: jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I need to make a Responsive Panel to stay open on wider screens using a pure CSS solution. I create  a short jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ezbdaft4/

In this example the menu button will disappear on wider screens (if the container is expanded). I need that panel to stay open also on wider screens (without scripts, only CSS).
The trigger should be `@media ( min-width: 35em ) {}` but I can not figure out how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery mobile - forcing panel open on wider screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960044/jquery-mobile-forcing-panel-open-on-wider-screens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but I think I've solved the problem. I'm writing here the solution in the hope that it will be useful to others.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/210woeLg/2/

**HTML**

```
  <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-display="push" data-theme="b" data-position-fixed="true" data-swipe-close="true" data-position="left">
    <ul data-role="listview">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Exit</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <a href="#mypanel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" class="hide-on-large-screen">menu</a>
    <h1>My App</h1>
  </div>

  <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="mycontent">
    <p>expand this container</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media ( min-width: 55em) {
  .ui-responsive-panel > .ui-header,
  .ui-responsive-panel > .ui-footer,
  .ui-responsive-panel > .ui-panel-wrapper {
    left: 17em;
    right: -17em;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 17em;
    margin-left: 1px;
  }
  .ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-page-content-position-left {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
  .ui-responsive-panel .ui-panel-animate {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
    -moz-transition: none;
    transition: none;
  }
  .ui-responsive-panel .ui-panel-closed {
    width: 17em;
    visibility: visible;
    clip: auto;
  }
  .ui-responsive-panel .ui-panel {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .ui-responsive-panel .ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-position-left.ui-panel-display-push {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
  .hide-on-large-screen {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```